# lftp mirror mode over hftp/proxy not working

Tags: proxy, ftp, mirroring, lftp

When I connect lftp over an http proxy using hftp and try to use mirror mode, no files are transferred. `dir` and `get` work fine.  Mirror mode works fine when I connect directly.  Here is the script I use to connect with identifying info removed:

```
debug 100
set ftp:ssl-allow false
set hftp:use-authorization no
set ftp:use-hftp yes
set http:proxy <proxy goes here>
set hftp:proxy <proxy goes here>
set ftp:proxy <proxy goes here>
open <url>
user <user> <password>
mirror --ignore-time  -r -c -P 1 ./<from>/ <to>
```

The debug output indicates that mirror mode does find files, but it doesn't say why it thinks there is nothing to transfer (the directory it is mirroring to does not have anything in it).

```
...
Found tag a, link_target=<file that does exist>
...
---- Closing HTTP connection
mirror(0x229fdc0) enters state TARGET_REMOVE_OLD_FIRST
mirror(0x229fdc0) enters state WAITING_FOR_TRANSFER
mirror(0x229fdc0) enters state TARGET_REMOVE_OLD
mirror(0x229fdc0) enters state TARGET_CHMOD
mirror(0x229fdc0) enters state FINISHING
mirror(0x229fdc0) enters state DONE
```

I've tried every option for mirror and everything that seems reasonable for set. Any ideas??

Comment: If you're using `--ignore-time`, how would it know which file is newer, and that it should go get the other copy or not?

Comment: have the same problem... Does mirror mode works with hftp?

Comment: It doesn't. Use an ftp proxy and don't forget to `set ftp:use-mlsd false`, because most ftp proxies don't support `MLSD`